# DropDownList The Name '' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, datagridview, gridview

Tenho uma gridview que lista os países e dependendo do selecionado lista as cidades desse país.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvRentalVendor" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="RetalAgency_Id" Width="824px" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" EmptyDataText="No records has been added.">
                <Columns> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="País" ItemStyle-Width="100">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country_Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCountry1" Height="39px" Width="190px" AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListarCidade1" OnTextChanged="ListarCidade1" OnDataBound="ListarCidade1">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cidade" ItemStyle-Width="100">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("city") %>' ></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCity1" Height="39px" Width="190px" AutoPostBack="true">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Porém não estou conseguindo fazer isso, pois quando utilizo o evento OnRowDataBound, já pega o valor padrão, não ação com qualquer outra alteração que o usuário fizer no dropdownlist, ou seja, o SelectedValue sempre está sendo o mesmo.

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && gvRentalVendor.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
        {
            DropDownList listVendor = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlVendor1");
            DropDownList listCountry = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCountry1");
            DropDownList listCity = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCity1");

            wsCarSuite csuite = new wsCarSuite();
            char[] language = Session["idioma"].ToString().ToCharArray();

            // Listar vendor
            DataSet dsVendor = LoadVendor(Convert.ToInt32(ddlContratos.SelectedValue));
            listVendor.DataSource = dsVendor.Tables[0];
            listVendor.DataValueField = "Vendor_Id";
            listVendor.DataTextField = "Name";
            listVendor.DataBind();

            // Listar Países
            DataSet dsCountry = ListCountryByLanguageAndVendor(Convert.ToInt32(listVendor.SelectedValue));
            listCountry.DataSource = dsCountry.Tables[0];
            listCountry.DataValueField = "CountryID";
            listCountry.DataTextField = "Nome";
            listCountry.DataBind();

            DataSet dsCity = listCityByCountry(listCountry.SelectedValue);
            listCity.DataSource = dsCity.Tables[0];
            listCity.DataValueField = "CityId";
            listCity.DataTextField = "city";
            listCity.DataBind();

            csuite.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Tentei criar alguns eventos para atualizar as cidades, como: `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListarCidade1" OnTextChanged="ListarCidade1" OnDataBound="ListarCidade1"`

Usando esse código aqui:

```
protected void ListarCidade1()
    {
        ddlCity.DataSource = listCityByCountry(ddlCountry1.SelectedValue);
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityId";
        ddlCity.DataTextField = "city";
        ddlCity.DataBind();
    }
```

No entanto, estou recebendo este erro no ddlCountry1. The Name 'ddlCountry1' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Para cada linha que você selecionar o País deve ser carregado suas cidades.
No caso, 3 linhas e você selecione Brasil, Argentina e Colômbia nessa ordem.
Exibe na linha 1 as cidades do Brasil, Linha 2 cidades da Argentita ......
é isso?

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo uns testes utilizando um código similar, primeiramente não estava conseguindo obter e carregar os DropDownList dentro do '**EditItemTemplate**'.
Então eu utilizei com o DropDownList dentro do '**ItemTemplate**'.

Utilizando o Evento em país '**OnSelectedIndexChanged**' com '**AutoPostBack="true"**', adicionei também um atributo para identificar qual o indice da linha '**indice='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>**'.

```
  `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="País" ItemStyle-Width="100">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCountry1" Height="39px" Width="190px"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListarCidade1"
                     DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="CountryID"  indice='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cidade" ItemStyle-Width="100">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCity1" Height="39px" Width="190px" AutoPostBack="true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>`
```

O evento disparado foi feito da seguinte maneira, obtém o índice da linha que detém o DropDownList de País, para assim obter o seu respectivo DropDownList de cidades, informando em qual coluna Cidade está.

```
protected void ListarCidade1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlCountry = (DropDownList)sender;
        int indice = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.Attributes["indice"]);
        DropDownList ddlCity = (DropDownList)gdvCidade.Rows[indice].Cells[1].FindControl("ddlCity1");
        ddlCity.DataSource = listCityByCountry(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityId";
        ddlCity.DataTextField = "city";
        ddlCity.DataBind();
    }
```

Se a Gridview possuir alguma ação no evento **Page_Load**, deve inserir o **!IsPostBack**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gvRentalVendor.DataSource = //Lista;
            gvRentalVendor.DataBind();
        }
    }
```